# How to independently manipulate/transform objects in Opengl?

Tags: opengl, transformation

I have cube and sphere in my Opengl environment. Which is created by

```
//Create Cube
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(-5.0,0.0,0.0);
glDrawCube(7.5f);
glPopMatrix();

//Create Sphere
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(10.0,0.0,0.0);
glDrawSphereIcosahedron(4.5f,6);    
glPopMatrix();
```

**What is Obtained:**
Cube and Sphere is created. The transformation/manipulation is dependent. If I try to rotate the cube, the sphere is also rotated along with it.

**What I want**
I want the cube and the sphere to have transformation/manipulation independent of each other. If I rotate the cube, the sphere shouldn't move/rotate

**What I tried**
I tried using glPushMatrix(), glloadMatrix() with the above code but it still has the same issue.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

If you put glRotate inside the glPushMatrix()/glPopMatrix() pair, the rotation will be applied only to object drawn inside the block. If you put glRotate outside this pair, this rotation will be applied to all object drawn after them

Comment: Thanks, yes your are correct about it. But it works only while its rendered initially. I want the cube to rotate independently while selecting the cube and not the sphere. I hope I am clear.

Comment: @khadkaboy What about this answer doesn't work for you? What does `only while its rendered initially` mean? This code needs to be in your main update loop if you want them to be rendered and rotated continuously.

Comment: @Dan I don't want the cubes to rotated continuously, rather I want to select an object(for now lets say cube) and then only manipulate the cube without making any changes or effect to the sphere created. But I am unable to do so.

Comment: @khadkaboy Store the rotation (presumably from user input) in a variable, and pass that variable to the glRotate call inside the glPush/glPop when you update the cube, but not when you update the sphere.